# What is the Discord "[]" control link feature called?

Tags: discord

I forgot about the Discord feature where you put "[]" and it has a link on the inside and you can make it show the login screen to the person that clicks it (as an example).

Can anyone help me on what this is called?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because discord is not a video game.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I disagree that that is a valid reason to close this looking at our other discord questions, but regardless I'm not sure it's clear what's being asked here.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz While Discord started out as a gaming platform, it no longer exclusively is. Nevertheless, the consensus on [Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/are-questions-about-discord-on-topic) is to allow questions about it.

Comment: @TimmyJim When you don't know what you're asking about, you tend to not use the official terms; you don't know what you don't know and you can't expect people to know so either.

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature of [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/); a [flavor](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/232451/128972) of which are used both on [Discord](https://discord.gg) AND the [Arqade](https://arqade.com)/[Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com).

You define a link by either pasting the whole link or using bracket notation:

```
https://example.com/link/to/thing
[Text to Display](https://example.com/link/to/thing)
```

It is then rendered as:

[image: StackOverflow/StackExchange/Arqade/Gaming.SE]

or:

[image: Discord]

You could [take a look at the markup for this answer to see how it's used](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/405435/edit).

---

Sidenote, SE has a second bracket notation you'd notice if you use images. It also works for links.

```
![Alt](img-url)
![Alt][url-id]
[Display Text][url-id]
... 
[url-id]: url-goes-here
```

Note that `url-id` are 1-indexed numbers.